# Does asp.net core rest api is thread safe?

Tags: asp.net

I use singleton manager in rest api method.

```
[HttpGet("GetUserData")]
public JsonResult GetUserData()
{
    //Singleton class in rest api method
    AuthManager manager = AuthManager.GetInstance();

}
```

Server will publish auth key when session(user) request login.
And Server will save this by Dictionary. 
The key is authkey and value is user info which include session id.

And my rest api must be used by logged in and authorized user, so i must check first session's authorized when the session request by rest api.
So all rest api must be access that singleton auth manager class.

But if it is not thread safe, then i must use lock (And it makes me very terrible).

Does asp.net core's controller method (view method or rest api) is thread safe?

Answer (score 1):

Self Answering.

No it's not thread safe to use singleton in mvc controller.

You must lock to synchronize the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Using something like a DI to inject your dependencies at the constructor level would help. netcore has its own built in container or you can use something like AutoFac